# Failed to delete account in app using android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

How do I deactivate authenticated user in the app? I followed in some guides in YouTube, but it didn't work. It says "Failed to delete your account". I already include get current user but it still failed to remove the account from firebase.

My java class:

```
public class GeneralSettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// private button edit text etc here


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_setting);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    fullName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    userName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    oldEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    password.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    newPassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changeFullname.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changeUsername.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changeEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    changePassword.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sendEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //get firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    //get current user
    userID = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    mTuteeDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Tutees").child(userID);

    getUserInfo();

    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();




    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(GeneralSettingActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    btnRemoveUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (user != null) {
                user.delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(GeneralSettingActivity.this, "Your profile is deleted:( Create a account now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(GeneralSettingActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(GeneralSettingActivity.this, "Failed to delete your account!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (authListener != null) {
        auth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}
}
```

had to remove some codes cause it wont let me post this questions because its mostly code

Comment: Firebase notes that the user has to have logged in recently in order to successfully delete so you may need to re-authenticate them before you can delete. Here is the code for [re-auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user).

Comment: Thank you, i forgot about that. My mistake hehe

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to first create credential for the user and then re-authenticate user with these credential. In `onSuccess()` of re-authenticate method you can successful delete the user. you can follow these steps:

> First get current user instance

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

> ask for user's email and password and create credentials and then delete user like this

```
 try {

        AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider
                .getCredential(email, password);
        if(user!=null) {
            user.reauthenticate(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
             user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(newOnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                      //user deleted successfully
                    }
              });
             }
          });
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        //error
    }

}
```

This worked for me. Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks! I missed that one after rewriting my whole code. I forgot to getcurrentuser / re authenticate